# my xammp does not start mysql and it does not tell me why

Tags: mysql

ok, so my xampp was working normally with mysql until today that i tried to start it and it hit me with:

```
Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
03:46:07 a. m.  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
03:46:07 a. m.  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
03:46:07 a. m.  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
03:46:07 a. m.  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
03:46:07 a. m.  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this
03:46:07 a. m.  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums
```

i went to the logs to see what the error was but it does not tell me anything all it sends its this:

```
2023-05-09  3:47:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2023-05-09  3:47:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2023-05-09  3:47:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.12
2023-05-09  3:47:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2023-05-09  3:47:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2023-05-09  3:47:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2023-05-09  3:47:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2023-05-09  3:47:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2023-05-09  3:47:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2023-05-09  3:47:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2023-05-09  3:47:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2023-05-09  3:47:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2023-05-09  3:47:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.27 started; log sequence number 3283617; transaction id 3997
2023-05-09  3:47:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2023-05-09  3:47:47 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2023-05-09  3:47:47 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

what is wrong with my xampp and how can i fix it?

Comment: Did you check windows event log as suggested by the error message before posting this question?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and couldn't find a solution. I chose to uninstall and reinstall xampp, luckily I had copies of my projects and my databases.